# Use an index for a string column

Tags: mysql

If I have a query with ordering by a string column, like this...

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY name
```

...should I create an index for `foo.name`? (`foo.name` may be `VARCHAR(255)` or `VARCHAR(400)`

Comment: Try to run EXPLAIN on that query and try to figure out if you need an index. Also, indices represent a performance hit on tables where you insert/update data often.

Comment: if it starts getting too slow... Is this your whole query? No filtering or paging?

Comment: no pagination and no filtering

Comment: 1 st thing is you have to limit the query

Comment: FYI, nvarchar length of 255 or 400 shouldn't have any influence on the answer itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you should create an index on name.

If you run queries with order_by by a column or where conditions by a columns, then those columns should be indexed.

It will increase the speed in which you get the result from any database.

But indexing should be used with caution. Too much of indexing may slow up your database.

You should index those columns which are searched frequently or ordered frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to affect, in MySQL with my test table. My test table is small, though. Explain revealed that Mysql has to do file sort in both the cases; with and without index.

Itz better to check your query with explain to confirm the same.